# Issue with images in Python graphics

Tags: python, zelle-graphics

I'm pretty inexperienced with Python and programming in general (I am taking a highschool course) and I need help.

```
if a2text=="midday":
    middayimage=Image(Point,(200,200), "midday.gif")
    sequence2=True
    middayimage.draw(win)
```

This is the code fragment that I'm getting an error from;

> File "C:\Users\Callie\python\graphics.py", line 817, in **init**
>   self.anchor = p.clone()
>   TypeError: clone() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Can anyone tell me why I'm getting this error? The rest of the code is much longer and I was wondering if there was something that I am doing wrong here because I can't really seem to find anywhere else I've done something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The error:

> TypeError: clone() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Is being caused by an errant comma:

```
Point,(200,200) -> Point(200,200)
```

The `Image` constructor takes two arguments a position and the name of an image, your extra comma gave it three argments and took away the arguments to the `Point` constructor.  Complete code fragment:

```
if a2text == "midday":
    middayimage = Image(Point(200, 200), "midday.gif")
    sequence2 = True
    middayimage.draw(win)
```